# Google API Client Libraries PHP - Remove unnecessary folders and files

Tags: php, api, composer-php, google-shopping-api

I just follow the instructions provided by google team, to communicate with the shopping API:

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
```

Everything works fine, I complete my integration (API for Shopping), nevertheless I realise now that when I download this google library, using composer:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

I have now around 6300 files to commit!!!

So, I will like to try to remove what for sure I will not need, since I just use API for google Shopping.
This is my current vendor/ ( or lib/) folders structures:

[image]

This a sample of my code that is already working correctly:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content');
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

$service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);
```

Even I never use some of features directly located in other folders (ex: monolog, etc), I'm not sure if they are or not necessary (I suppose not) for google api.

So I will like to have confirmation, of the folders that could be removed safely and everything that allow google api shopping works correctly are not affected.

Comment: Don't commit the vendor directory at all, just the composer.json/lock so that the vendor folder can be reproduced. And you should probably not try to remove unused dependencies that were included by the google api, that might break things now or in the future. Having a huge vendor-folder is usually not a problem, only the files you use will contribute to the actual "load".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those files are required dependencies of the google API project. You should never commit composer's vendor directory into your VCS repository. You should utilize the feature of your VCS for ignoring files/directories to prevent you from accidentally committing those dependency files.

Comment: ok, its seems clear to me that vendor folder/file, shouldn't be in repo, and I just need to let the 2 files composer.json/lock like @martinSuecia also recommended.
But how the framework, will load find the require autoload file and all others?

Comment: Committing only the composer.json and lock file, I will have this error msg:  

`PHP Warning:  require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in ...`

Comment: After pulling the project freshly from the VCS, you will need to run the `composer install` command to pull the dependencies down.

Comment: ok, so it means that will have the same qty of folders/files.
The only point in all this is not have them in repo.
If this is correct, it means if for some reason something happens to one of this files (not committed ), the only option will be use compose again etc...
Will be more advantage have them in repo directly? Without the need to install composer in live server?

Comment: The point of composer is dependency management. The google API project requires every one of those dependencies. If you don't want to use composer, you can most certainly manage the dependencies on your own and commit them to your repo. However, you will need to commit all of those files.

Comment: Exactly makes very much sense to use composer in the case that we need to maintain dependency. Could you recommend me the folders that almost sure I will not need? Any idea about the extra tools found in that structure? Or any recommend lecture that could send be in the good direction.

Comment: All of the libraries in the vendor directory are required by the google API. The library requires all of them in order to work. Without them you will get errors.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for for your help, really appreciate!

Comment: Yet another reason why composer is such a bad idea in a production environment.

Comment: @IncredibleHat if you have a proper pipeline for building and deploying artifacts, this isn't a problem. If you are doing a VCS checkout on your production server, you are doing it wrong....