# Get rid of unnecessary dependencies in Google api lib

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, composer-php

**Background**

I have implemented user authentication using Google services in client and server side successfully. I've used [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) on the server side for this purpose (get the token from the client and save the result on the server after further authentication).

**What the doc is said**

There is a section in readme.md entitled [Cleaning up unused services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#cleaning-up-unused-services) :

> There are over 200 Google API services. The chances are good that you will not want them all. In order to avoid shipping these dependencies with your code, you can run the Google\Task\Composer::cleanup task and specify the services you want to keep in composer.json

**Another answer**

It seems that I can get rid of (at least) some of that huge lib, **but** there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133300) in StackOverflow that doesn't agree (the comment specially):

> ... And you should probably not try to remove unused dependencies that were included by the google api, that might break things now or in the future

**Question**

I need to get rid of any unnecessary dependencies successfully peacefully. Is it possible? If yes then how about the comment? If not then what is the purpose of the "cleaning" section in the readme?

**What answers I am looking for**

In the first place I want to know the Why and the How (learning composer). In the second place any workaround is accepted. I really don't like to upload all of the lib.

Comment: The best practice is to only use the libraries you require. You probably don't want to hear this but you are using an old library that has been replaced for most but not all APIs. Unless disk space was an absolute premium, I would not bother trying to strip the SDK. I would either leave the dependencies alone or update my code to use the latest SDKs which have smaller footprints or go directly to the REST API (which is very easy). Your question does not clearly define which APIs you are using therefore an answer is difficult.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I really didn't know that I've used an old API, I just followed the docs. I am using google services for user authentication (OAuth) therefore user don't need to sign up in the first place. What is the best practice for that?

Comment: I am not certain what would be a best practice for your case. OAuth is very easy to implement. You do not even need libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> In the first place I want to know the Why and the How (learning composer).

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Task/Composer.php#L31

> I really don't like to upload all of the lib.

You can't: `google/apiclient` has dependency `google/apiclient-services` (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services) containing all  packages