# How can reduce package size of the Google API PHP Client by using composer.json extra configuration?

Tags: php, google-sheets, composer-php

I am using the google-api-php-client in the WP plugin and the PHP composer downloading the complete git repo with almost 200 libraries so the size of the plugin is increasing due to that. 
is there a way to get only the desired single package like sheet, drive, etc from this repo by using the PHP composer? 
I have tested the following configuration but it is not working.

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive",
            "YouTube"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you achieve "almost 200 libraries"? I've took this `composer.json` and after "composer update", the command "composer show | wc -l" returns 18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get ride of any unnecessary dependencies in google api lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958260/get-ride-of-any-unnecessary-dependencies-in-google-api-lib)